# Unity Can Not Play Disabled Audio Source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have the audio source set to not destroy, and it's continuing to play the original song it was set to, but I cannot play the new song I'm trying to set it to. I have checked other questions asking the same answer and attempted their solutions, but cannot get it to work.

```
 private void Awake()
 {
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
 }

 private void Start()
 {
     Load();
     audioSource.Play();
     cheatCount = 0;

     if (volumeOff)
     {
         AudioListener.volume = 0.0f;
     } else
     {
         AudioListener.volume = 1.0f;
     }
 }

 public void LoadLevel(string name)
 {
     Save();
     Scene current = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
     string currentName = current.name;
     lastScene = currentName;
     SceneManager.LoadScene(name);

     if (name == "Level2")
     {
         audioSource.clip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Audio\\Escape! Soundtrack10");
         audioSource.enabled = true;
         audioSource.Play();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is the second clip definitely being set as the audio source clip? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Have you tried storing that AudioClip in an AudioClip variable and checking if it is null?

Comment: Yes. The source is coming up null, but the clip is not. I have tried just stopping the source, not loading a new clip, on a changed scene, and it still fails.

Comment: if your audioSource is null, then you cant use it for anything, how are you setting your audioSource?

Comment: Lets try something, in your start method before you do anything with audioSource try putting this line of code in there... `audioSource = getComponent<AudioSource>();`